# eBPF uprobe problem with some addresses and/or static binary - Maximum uprobe address?

Tags: c++, static, linker, elf, ebpf

I have a simple C++ program with the function `fibonacci`, where I want to attach a uprobe.
With normal linking, this works finde. **But with static linking, I get an error attaching to the new adress.**

My machine:

- Raspbian 5.15.45, arm aarch64 Raspberry Pi 4
- The function I want to attach to is called "fibonacci", just a normal C++ function in a simple program.

Dynamic linking:
With `objdump --syms fibonacci` I get the address 0x3b03c:

```
000000000003b03c g     F .text  0000000000000062              _Z9fibonaccim
```

So I tell the bpf loader to attach the uprobe to `0x3b03c`.
**This works fine.**

For building, I use CMAKE:

```
list(APPEND SOURCES main.cc)
add_executable(fibonacci ${SOURCES})
list(APPEND EXTRA_INCLUDES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/[...]/json/include/")
target_include_directories(fibonacci PUBLIC
                           "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
                           ${EXTRA_INCLUDES}
                           )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0")   # Disable optimization
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0")
install(TARGETS fibonacci DESTINATION "${PROJECT_BUILD_DIR}/")
```

`VERBOSE=1 make` yields

```
/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-9   -I/home/[...]/build -I/home/[...]/json/include  -g -O0   -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/fibonacci.dir/main.cc.o -c /home/[...]/main.cc

/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-9  -g -O0  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/fibonacci.dir/main.cc.o  -o fibonacci
```

**Problems raise if I add the line `target_link_libraries(fibonacci -static)`** to the CMakeLists.txt.

`VERBOSE=1 make` yields

```
/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-9   -I/home/[...]/build -I/home/[...]/json/include  -g -O0   -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/fibonacci.dir/main.cc.o -c /home/[...]/main.cc

/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-9  -g -O0  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/fibonacci.dir/main.cc.o  -o fibonacci  -static
```

The only difference is the `-static` for linking.

`objdump --syms fibonacci` shows that the address changed to 0x401424:

```
0000000000401424 g     F .text  0000000000000062 _Z9fibonaccim
```

**Now, attaching the bpf program to the new address does not work anymore.**
I get the following output:

```
libbpf: loading [...]uprobe_fibonacci_0x401424.bpf.o
libbpf: elf: section(3) kprobe/xxx, size 200, link 0, flags 6, type=1
libbpf: sec 'kprobe/xxx': found program 'main_entry' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 25 insns (200 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(4) .relkprobe/xxx, size 16, link 21, flags 0, type=9
libbpf: elf: section(5) license, size 4, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: license of [...]uprobe_fibonacci_0x401424.bpf.o is GPL
libbpf: elf: section(6) .maps, size 32, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(13) .BTF, size 1666, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(15) .BTF.ext, size 268, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(21) .symtab, size 1512, link 1, flags 0, type=2
libbpf: looking for externs among 63 symbols...
libbpf: collected 0 externs total
libbpf: map 'runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0': at sec_idx 6, offset 0.
libbpf: map 'runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0': found type = 2.
libbpf: map 'runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0': found key [2], sz = 4.
libbpf: map 'runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0': found value [7], sz = 16.
libbpf: map 'runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0': found max_entries = 1.
libbpf: sec '.relkprobe/xxx': collecting relocation for section(3) 'kprobe/xxx'
libbpf: sec '.relkprobe/xxx': relo #0: insn #19 against 'runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0'
libbpf: prog 'main_entry': found map 0 (runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0, sec 6, off 0) for insn #19
err from bpf_object__open_file: Success (0)
Getting programs
err from prog: Success (0)
Checking maps
- Found map runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0
Done loading bpf object file.
libbpf: map 'runtimeSimpleCtx_storage_0': created successfully, fd=4
libbpf: sec 'kprobe/xxx': found 1 CO-RE relocations
libbpf: CO-RE relocating [19] struct user_pt_regs: found target candidate [200] struct user_pt_regs in [vmlinux]
libbpf: prog 'main_entry': relo #0: <byte_off> [19] struct user_pt_regs.regs[0] (0:0:0 @ offset 0)
libbpf: prog 'main_entry': relo #0: matching candidate #0 <byte_off> [200] struct user_pt_regs.regs[0] (0:0:0 @ offset 0)
libbpf: prog 'main_entry': relo #0: patched insn #3 (ALU/ALU64) imm 0 -> 0
Object load: Success (0)
Attaching uprobe uprobe_fibonacci_0x401424.bpf.o to fibonacci/0x401424
- PID: 5026
- Address: 0x401424
libbpf: uprobe perf_event_open() failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: prog 'main_entry': failed to create uprobe '/proc/5026/exe:0x401424' perf event: Invalid argument
- ERROR: Invalid argument (-22)
```

I wrote a loop to try all the addresses:

```
cout << "hacky test" << endl;
for(uint64_t i = address; i != 0; --i)
{
    link = bpf_program__attach_uprobe_opts( prog,
                                            pid /* pid */,
                                            execPath.c_str(),
                                            i,
                                            &opts);
    if(libbpf_get_error(link) != 0)
    {
        cout << i << ": " << bpfGetError(link) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << i << ": SUCCESS!: " << bpfGetError(link) << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

This leads to the output

```
2625179: Invalid argument (-22)
libbpf: uprobe perf_event_open() failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: prog 'main_entry': failed to create uretprobe '/proc/5026/exe:0x280e9a' perf event: Invalid argument
2625178: Invalid argument (-22)
libbpf: uprobe perf_event_open() failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: prog 'main_entry': failed to create uretprobe '/proc/5026/exe:0x280e99' perf event: Invalid argument
2625177: Invalid argument (-22)
2625176: SUCCESS!: Success (0)
```

The addresses do not look like any pattern to me:

- 4199460 = 0h401424 = 0b010000000001010000100100  - ERROR
- 2625177 = 0h280E99 = 0b001010000000111010011001  - ERROR
- 2625176 = 0h280E98 = 0b001010000000111010011000  - OK

Attaching to the pid with gdb shows that the function `fibonacci` is at the expected address 0x401424, whereas gdb cannot read the memory on location 0x280e9a or 0x280e99.

**Therefore, I can attach uprobes to random looking addresses where there should not be anything, but not to the address of my function.**

The pid (5026) is correct (checked in htop).

Does somebody have any idea what could be wrong?
Thanks in advance!